# Apostrophe placement issue

Tags: symbols, positioning

I'm trying to typeset word form `DARPA's` and I'm experiencing some issues with spacing the *apostrophe* in relation to the neighboring letters. In particular, if I just use the text as is, LaTeX places apostrophe too close to the `A`, whereas, if I use `DARPA~'s`, this results in too much distance between `DARPA` and `'s`. I would appreciate advice on fixing this.

Comment: DARPA's is the correct markup, perhaps there is a problem with the kerning in the font that you are using but you have given no indication of font or any other details.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you for fast feedback. I'm using the standard `charter` font.

Comment: you've been on the site long enough to know it helps if you give an example document, show your output, say whether you are using xetex or luatex or pdftex. I don't seem to have a font called charter so I can't comment on its apostrophe kerning.

Comment: you might insert just a `{}` before the apostrophe, or `\/`, to discourage kerning.  or if a small space is really needed, then `\,` is much smaller than `~` (and won't break either).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sure, I can create an MWE - I just thought that this issue is too simple for that. Let me see what Barbara suggests - hopefully, her suggestion will solve my problem ...

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh as i say the markup is DARPA's, or you can use DARPA\kern2cm' or whatever space you want, but if your question is why the standard markup produces a bad result, it is entirely about details not in your question, namely the font and the tex engine used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Understood. Thank you for clarification. I will test some variants and will produce MWE (or provide more details), if the issue will persist.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thank you for the advice. I just tried `\,` - it's a bit better, but still not ideal. However, [drum roll] your suggested `DARPA{'}s` and `DARPA\/'s` (any preference?) produce the expected nice result. Your help is much appreciated. Please convert your comment into an answer, so I could upvote and accept it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Admittedly, it is hard to help when basic information are missing, but reg. your comment you don't have `charter`, it comes with TL, see `tlmgr info charter`.

Comment: @ArashEsbati hmm I guessed xetex or luatex and `\setmainfont{charter}` and it found nothing...

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that currently I use `pdflatex` and `TeXstudio` on Windows 7 to build my application documents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is clearly in the kerning instructions in the font, so what you
want to do is inhibit kerning.  there are several ways to do that:

- `DARPA{}'s` -- an empty group
- `DARPA\/'s` -- an italic correction
- `DARPA{'}s` -- isolate the apostrophe in its own group

your choice -- they should all have the same result.

warning -- if the passage containing this string goes through an additional
pass for the purpose of hyphenation/justification, the first two might be
lost, although this particular string is probably not a candidate for
hyphenation.

**update:**
other possibilities suggested in comments:

- `DARPA\kern0pt's` -- explicit zero-width kern (Heiko Oberdiek)
- `DARPA\mbox{'}s` -- boxed, and therefore "structurally" isolated,
  apostrophe (Manuel)

as also noted in the comments, which approach is chosen depends on both
the shapes of the affected pair of characters and the circumstances, e.g. whether or not the text may undergo hyphenation.  the grouped and boxed
instances also affect the interaction with the next character in the string.

Comment: I appreciate your simple, clear and general answer.

Comment: `DARPA{}'s` and `DARPA{'}s` can lost the group, when hyphenated. `\/` adds a kern, which prevents the implicit kerning. In general, `\/` can even insert additional space, which might be too much (not in this case). AFAIK, the reliable way to prevent implicit kerning without adding additional space is `\kern0pt` between the letters in question.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Thank you for clarification. While I understand the basic concept of kerning, its control in LaTeX (as we as fonts' features control) seems to be quite complicated (or, rather, overwhelming) for me at the moment.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh See Wikipedia's article about [Kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) for introduction/explanation.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek or `\mbox{'}`? That's what I use sometimes.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that methods 1 ("`DARPA{}'s`") and 3 ("`DARPA{'}s`") don't succeed if LuaLaTeX is used. (The underlying reason is the same as for the case of trying to suppress ligatures: `shelf{}ful` doesn't succeed under LuaLaTeX if the objective is to break up the `ff` ligature, whereas `\shelf\kern0ptful` does.)

Answer (score 5):

If you use `xcharter` there seems to be no problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{XCharter}%
\begin{document}

DARPA’s

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: … which is, also, probably the best way of using Charter font in pdfTeX.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer (+1). I wasn't aware of the `xcharter` package. While I will accept Barbara's simpler and more general answer, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

There is an implicit kerning between the upper case A and the apostrophe, if the font package `charter` is used. Because of the shape of the A, a negative kerning makes sense. It's not a bug, but by choice of the font designer.

The following example compares three cases:

- Unmodified version with implicit kernings as defined by the font.
- Without implicit kernings, removed by adding `\kern0pt`.
- Words with uppercase letters are better readable, if some small letter spacing is added. This is done by package `microtype`'s `\textls` command.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{charter}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

  \noindent
  DARPA's\\ % unmodified
  D\kern0pt ARP\kern0pt A\kern0pt's\\ % without implicit kerning
  \textls[25]{DARPA's}% small letter spacing

\showboxdepth=\maxdimen  
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\tracingonline=1
\nonstopmode
\showlists
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Log result for the unmodified version, which shows the kerning values:

```
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 D
.\kern-0.19
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 A
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 R
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 P
.\kern-0.93001
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 A
.\kern-1.3
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 '
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 s
```

The version with inserted zero spaces, `\kern0pt`, does not have positive or negative space between letters:

```
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 D
.\kern 0.0
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 A
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 R
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 P
.\kern 0.0
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 A
.\kern 0.0
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 '
.\OT1/bch/m/n/10 s
```

The letter spacing version of package `letterspace` is included in the font as can be seen in the font name: `\OT1/bch/m/n/10/25ls`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for such a detailed answer (+1). It's a little too complex for my level of LaTeX knowledge, so I will accept Barbara's simpler answer. Nevertheless, your time and effort are much appreciated.